# Vectorise Python code

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have coded a kriging algorithm but I find it quite slow. Especially, do you have an idea on how I could vectorise the piece of code in the cons function below:

```
import time
import numpy as np

B = np.zeros((200, 6))
P = np.zeros((len(B), len(B)))

def cons():
  time1=time.time()
  for i in range(len(B)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
      P[i,j] = corr(B[i], B[j])
  time2=time.time()
  return time2-time1

def corr(x,x_i):
  return np.exp(-np.sum(np.abs(np.array(x) - np.array(x_i))))    

time_av = 0.
for i in range(30):
  time_av+=cons()
print "Average=", time_av/100.
```

---

Edit: Bonus questions

1. What happens to the broadcasting solution if I want `corr(B[i], C[j])` with C the same dimension than B
2. What happens to the scipy solution if my p-norm orders are an array:

   ```
   p=np.array([1.,2.,1.,2.,1.,2.])
   def corr(x, x_i):
     return np.exp(-np.sum(np.abs(np.array(x) - np.array(x_i))**p))
   ```

   For 2., I tried `P = np.exp(-cdist(B, C,'minkowski', p))` but scipy is expecting a scalar.

Comment: @TobySpeight while CR *only* accepts working code, I don't think all performance-improvement questions are off-topic here. [This here says so too](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5778).

Comment: Don't add details that would require the posted solution(s) to be modified significantly. Instead, post a new question with those new details and if reqd. linking to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem seems very simple to vectorize. For each pair of rows of `B` you want to compute

```
P[i,j] = np.exp(-np.sum(np.abs(B[i,:] - B[j,:])))
```

You can make use of array broadcasting and introduce a third dimension, summing along the last one:

```
P2 = np.exp(-np.sum(np.abs(B[:,None,:] - B),axis=-1))
```

The idea is to reshape the first occurence of `B` to shape `(N,1,M)` while the second `B` is left with shape `(N,M)`. With array broadcasting, the latter is equivalent to `(1,N,M)`, so

```
B[:,None,:] - B
```

is of shape `(N,N,M)`. Summing along the last index will then result in the `(N,N)`-shape correlation array you're looking for.

---

Note that if you were using `scipy`, you would be able to do this using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) (or, equivalently, a combination of `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` and `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`), without unnecessarily computing the lower triangular half of this symmetrix matrix. Using [@Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar)'s suggestion in comments for the simplest solution this way:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
P3 = 1/np.exp(cdist(B, B, 'minkowski',1))
```

`cdist` will compute the Minkowski distance in 1-norm, which is exactly the sum of the absolute values of coordinate differences.

Comment: Thus, `1/np.exp(pdist(B, 'minkowski',1))` or `1/np.exp(cdist(B, B, 'minkowski',1))` could be added there I guess.

Comment: @Divakar yeah, I didn't want to be too explicit because OP doesn't seem to use scipy, so an additional import might be overkill. But I'll add it anyway:) Also, thanks for `cdist`, I wasn't aware of its existence.

Comment: Very complete answer, thanks.@AndrasDeak Indeed, I would like to avoid using scipy but the cdist function looks very insteresting. You point out the fact that the lower triangular matrix is uselessly computed, and in my code I actually have the second for loop starting from i+1: `for j in range(i+1, len(B))`, any chance to achieve that with your first solution?

Comment: @Jean not with array broadcasting, I don't think so. If depending on scipy is not an issue, I suggest that you time both the redundant numpy version and the scipy one; you might find that even with the overhead of importing once scipy will be the fastest.

Comment: So for the timing I get, with an average over 100 tries: my solution: 0.339s, array broadcasting: 0.00393s and scipy (without import time): 0.00333s.

Comment: @Jean thanks for the feedback:) That's along what I'd expect, maybe the difference between numpy and scipy would be more significant for very large arrays. Anyway, I would go with either of those.